# using query_posts to pull posts out of a category in a while loop. Getting odd echo

Tags: query-posts, post-content, get-post

I have a custom template file I've been workin on. I have this code performing a loop after it queries posts from a certain category. This works and I have each post configured with styled divs, but for some reason, on the side of the page, I have strange numbers being displayed. I don't understand where they are coming from. The most posts in a category, the more numbers.

Example #'s on page: 65138
I believe the 138 is the post ID of one of the posts being called in my while loop. I'm not sure what the 65 means. Am I using a function that is echoing these values for some reason and I don't know it??

```
<?php
 // Select the category to get posts from.
$posts_of_interest = query_posts('cat=5');
$num_of_posts = count($posts_of_interest);
if(have_posts()) :
while( $i <= $num_of_posts):
    $i++;
    $queried_post = get_post(the_ID());
    echo $queried_post->post_content;   
    the_post();
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you absolutely need to modify the main query, you should be using `get_posts()` instead of `query_posts()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `the_ID()` to `get_the_ID()`. calling `the_ID()` prints the post's ID, while `get_the_ID()` simply returns it and allows you to use it further on.

reference : [get_the_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)

Comment: no problem! glad i could help :D